# Is there a way to slow down all animations on the emulator?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

On the iPhone emulator, I can set the emulator to use slow animations.  This allows me to carefully watch the animation, and check for visual problems.  Is there a way to do the same thing for the Android emulator, either through a setting, or through some type of operating system trick?  Obviously, I can increase the time for custom animations and do it that way, but that wouldn't help with built-in animations such as Activity transitions.

Comment: Just increase the emulator's resolution. The damn thing should slow down to a crawl :) lol

Answer (score 5):

In the device developer settings you can slow down window animation, transition animation and animator duration. This last item slows down anything based on an underlying `Animator` object, which is quite effective for animation debugging in my experience.

Go to:

`Settings app -> Developer settings -> Drawing -> Animator duration scale`

You can then change the scale multiplier to speed up or slow down animations as you wish.

Comment: This link is dead

Comment: @GregoryYanushkovskiy Thanks for the head up, I've edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Some animations can be slowed down by using the Developers settings screen. Future versions of Android will allow you to slow down all (or at least most) animations.

Comment: have these future versions come out yet?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio you can:
open "Flutter performance" tab -> click "Open DevTools" -> click button "Slow animations"